# Reduce distance between toolbar icons

Tags: android, icons, padding, toolbar

[image]

I have two icons on my toolbar menu. How can I reduce the space between these two icons? Distance between icon is larger than the right padding of last icon or like left padding of first icon.

Comment: post your xlm code plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AppTheme add below line

```
<item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MenuItemStyle</item>
```

create style in `style.xml`

```
    <style name="MenuItemStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingStart">8dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingEnd">8dip</item>
    </style>
```

Hope it helps!